# How to remove parentheses only when the whole text is surrounded by them?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I want to remove parentheses only when the whole text is surrounded by them. For example:

```
(text (text) text)
```

need's to be convert to:

```
text (text) text
```

I have a very simple check:

```
value = (value [0] == '(' && value [value .Length - 1] == ')') ? value.Substring(1, value .Length - 2) : value;
```

but it fails and incorrectly removes the parentheses of these kind of strings:

```
(text (text) ) text (text)
```

Could anyone tell a way to handle all cases? Using regular expression is `OK` as well.

Note, that the parentheses are balanced. For example, such case is not possible:

```
( text ( text )
```

Comment: In your failure case, the "whole text" is not surrounded by parenthesis, which is apparently what you want to fix, could you restate the problem you are attempting to solve?

Comment: can the `text` in ur example contain spaces??

Comment: Regex is not suitable for this. It lacks ability to do parsing and "remember" context. It's fairly simple to do with a loop though.

Comment: You also have (text (text) ) (text (text))  The best thing you can do (I think) is do a foreach(chac c in string) and map each close to an open and the last will match to the first or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple loop for testing, if it's "valid" for removal, remove first & last:

```
bool isValid = value[0] == '(' && value[value.Length - 1] == ')';
int i = 1;
int c = 0;
for(; isValid && c >= 0 && i < value.Length - 1; i++)
{
  if(value[i] == '(')
    c++;
  else if(value[i] == ')')
    c--;
}

if(isValid && i == (value.Length - 1) && c == 0)
  value = value.Substring(1, value.Length - 2);
```

Comment: its more wrong now. `i` and `c` should both start from 0. also you must break loop when `c` equals to 0. (check `c == 0` at the end of loop)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - no, they shouldn't... i = 0 has already been validated, and as Eric just suggested, it can even be improved by checking the last char.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: I don't understand your comment; the first character has already been processed by checking in the initialization of `isValid`. If it is true then there is one character processed and the count is one open paren. Also, the code does check if c is equal to zero, in the loop condition. It is a non-negative number, so checking whether it is greater than zero is sufficient.

Comment: this is working now. but it was better if you start `c` from 1 and break loop at c = 0. that makes more sense.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - I don't think it makes much "sense" this way or the other. It's just supposed to be simple and working. Whether the count is for all parenthesis, or just those inside the outer ones (and hence negative is illegal) makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

This extension method should work;

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveParentheses(this string value)
    {
        if (value == null || value[0] != '(' || value[value.Length - 1 ] != ')') return value;

        var cantrim = false;
        var openparenthesesIndex = new Stack<int>();
        var count = 0;
        foreach (char c in value)
        {
            if (c == '(')
            {
                openparenthesesIndex.Push(count);
            }
            if (c == ')')
            {
                cantrim = (count == value.Length - 1 && openparenthesesIndex.Count == 1 && openparenthesesIndex.Peek() == 0);
                openparenthesesIndex.Pop();
            }
            count++;
        }

        if (cantrim)
        {
            return value.Trim(new[] { '(', ')' });
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
Console.WriteLine("(text (text) ) text (text)".RemoveParentheses());
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran a few test cases and I think this is good

```
public string CleanString(string CleanMe)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CleanMe)) return CleanMe;
    string input = CleanMe.Trim();
    if (input.Length <= 2) return input;
    if (input[0] != '(') return input;
    if (input[input.Length-1] != ')') return input;
    int netParen = 1;  // starting loop at 1 have one paren already
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < input.Length-1; i++)
    {
        char c = input[i];
        sb.Append(c);
        if (c == '(') netParen++;
        else if (c == ')') netParen--;
        if (netParen == 0) return input;  // this is the key did the () get closed out
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I started this before the answer from Amit but I think it is the same basic logic